# Getting data from an Input control in to code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, forms, jquery-ui

I am using asp.net C#
I am also using the jQuery UI Calendar control. 
[calendar control](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

It appears the calendar control wants to work with an input control with an ID of "datepicker".

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"  />
```

I want to use value of the input control in my code behind but seeing how it is not an asp.net control I am not sure how I can reference it in the code behind.

Does anyone know how to get the value of the input control in the code behind?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" />
```

and in the code behind:

```
Request.Form["datepicker"]
```

In fact, Form property of Request is populated with form values.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have to mention your form name which contains input tag

```
<input name="txtemail" id="txtemail" runat="server" type="text" class="cssspa" form="form"/>
```

in C# 
string email = txtemail.Value.ToString();

now u can get data from textbox

Comment: what if the OP doesn't want a server control?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use basic form pulling, you need to add a name attribute:

```
 <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" />

 if(Page.IsPostBack)
 {
     string value = Request.Form["datepicker"];
 }
```

Alternatively, you can mark is as an `HtmlInputControl`

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" runat="server" />

System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputControl datepickerControl = this.FindControl("datepicker") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputControl;

if(datepickerControl != null)
    string value = datepickerControl.Value;
```

Comment: adding runat=server would not change the id rendered on the page?

Comment: Apologies. Yes, it will change the ID rendered on the page. You can use `ClientIDMode="Static"` if on ASP.NET 4, or you can use `$('<$= datepicker.ClientID %>')` if you want to select the generated id via jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value via the Request object like onof wrote, or you can turn every html tag into a server control by adding the attribute runat:

```
 <input type="text" id="datepicker" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static" />
```

The attribute ClientIdMode="static" ensures that the tags ID is not changed by the ASP.NET runtime.

Then you can access the input by the autogenerated member `datePicker`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you explicitly say code-behind, I assume you probably want to stay with the WebForms/Controls model?  With clientidmode you can do that while also having a determinite id value for the calendar.

```
<asp:TextBox id="datepicker" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

Then you can interact directly with the control from the code-behind as normal.

But, the calendar control does not require a specific ID.  You can initialize it with whatever ID you want

```
<asp:TextBox id="DateTextBox" runat="server" />

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#<%=DateTextBox.ClientID%>" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```